# How to auto save complex model with lists of models in it?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js

I am creating a quiz creator module. There are 5 subjects. Each subject has 2000 questions.

Say, it's called "Create Full model test", and it will contain 100 questions, 20 questions from 5 subjects. So, 20*5=100

In the UI, creator will first select "Create full model test" from the drop down. Suppose if he select the "Full model test". He will have to select one subject among 5 subjects, then he will have to select 20 questions per subject. and then will have to save them into that "Full model test" segment.

If he selects English, he will have to select 20 questions, then he will have to select another subject, for example, physics, and will have to select another 20 questions for physics, then he will have to select maths and then will have to select another 20 questions and so on for maths. Finally 100 questions will be submitted by the form.

Now, my question is, how can I auto save the selected questions into that "Full model test" segment, so that he can continue saving 5 subject's questions before he submit the form.

Here is my Department model:

```
namespace MvcBCS.Models
{
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Section> Section { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subsection> Subsection { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is my Subject Model:

```
namespace MvcBCS.Models
{
public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    public string SubjectCode { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Section> Section { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is the Section Model:

```
namespace MvcBCS.Models
{
public class Section
{

    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Subject")]
    public int? SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

    [Key]

    public int SectionId { get; set; }

    public string SectionName { get; set; }


}
}
```

Here is the subjection model:

```
namespace MvcBCS.Models
{
public class Subsection
{

    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Subject")]
    public int? SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Section")]
    public int? SectionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int SubsectionId { get; set; }
    public string SubsectionName { get; set; }
    public string SubsectionCode { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Having the "auto save" in your title has me a bit confused. Are you meaning that you want to save the 20 questions per subject as the subjects get completed, or just having all of those be part of the full form that gets saved?

Comment: Looks that you have model which easily can be copied on client side. So you just need to save all data between subjects on client side.

Comment: @krillgar I want to save 20 question per subject. questions will be selected using html checkbox attribute and then want to save the form finally so that 100 questions from 5 subjects will be saved using a single submit button.

Comment: @U10, I will be able to parse questions, but I need to select 20 question per subject and then want to save 100 questions using a single submit form.

Comment: In case when you are storing data is JavaScript you don't need a form itself. When you will send data via Ajax it will create form by itself.

Comment: @mmahbub Check out this link for layered drop down or autocomplete calls that filters the drop depending on parent object. http://aspnetawesome.com/

Answer (score 8):

All that you need is just to store all temporary data on client side. 
And when you get complete pasts or even full set of data - send it to server using POST/JSON/XML/etc.

I think it such case it will be better for you **to use some kind of JavaScript frameworks**, for example [**KnockoutJS**](http://knockoutjs.com/), which with only **few click's** and **couple lines of code** will allows you **to store all your data on client side in object-based model**.

Anyway if you will use any framework or not, **you should use JavaScript** to store all of your data, including question, answers and subjects. JavaScript will allows you to **store,validate and send all data that you need**.

To make your work with JavaScript easier and faster - you can use [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) library which contains functions for **interaction with both DOM structure and server side**.

To make learning of KnockoutJS easier just use tutorial: http://learn.knockoutjs.com

Comment: Should I put my code here so that I can get a detail answer based on my project? I am stuck!

Comment: Sure! I think we can choose correct solution for you.

Comment: But also you should start with taking a look on KnockoutJS

Comment: I will start looking at knockoutJS.But does knockoutJS use MVVM? or MVC?

Comment: KnockoutJS use MVVM, because it is much simpler and don't need such big infrastructure as MVC does.

Comment: Can you show me an example of selecting multiple data and then saving it using one submit button using KnockoutJS? [like my problem]

Comment: You should just try tutorial, it contains all needed samples and explanations: http://learn.knockoutjs.com

Comment: Have you found an answer on your question?

Comment: No, still I have not found any.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I am going to attempt it.

business rules: 
-   full model test will be completed if all the subjects questions are submitted by certain user.

Assumption: we knew in advance that we have five subjects. Therefore

```
public enum Subject
{
    English,
    Physics,
    ...
}
```

Test Poco entity structure:

```
public class Test
{
public int Id{get;set;}
public User CreatedBy{get;set;}
public Subject Subject{get;set;}
public bool IsFullTestCompleted{get;set;}

public string Question1{get;set;}
public string Question2{get;set;}
...
}
```

Assumptions:
You can use partial views/ajax/Jquery/Angularjs/Knockout whatever suits you best in your  
problem context to implement it to auto save the changes

You will add necessary view model with appropriate validation annotations/attributes

you will add validation where necessary.

you will add/update the Test entity. like for first subject you will add data into Test entity, and subsequently you will update it.

Hope it will be helpful